# IN python how to pass variable in SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql

I know we can pass variable in SQL in python like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])
```

But I'm trying to create a database after user input and facing error. This is the code which is not working:

```
import mysql.connector;
host = input("ENter Host name ");
user = input("ENter Username ");
password = input("ENter password ");

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = host,
    user = user,
    password = password
);

connect = conn.cursor();
print("Connection Setup");
db = input("Enter Database Name ");
connect.execute('CREATE DATABASE %s',(db,));
print("Database ",db," created successfully");
connect.execute("SHOW DATABASES");

for x in connect:
    print(x);
```

But I'm not able to create the database... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind I found the answer. Here it is

```
connect.execute("""CREATE DATABASE {}""".format(db));
```

Just the wrong formatting on my end.
you can use this as well

```
connect.execute("CREATE DATABASE {}".format(db));
```

Comment: bteer will be zo add `IF NOT EXISTS` i don't see any code that prevents the code from running when you already have such a database